# CFMail is not working in ColdFusion 10

Tags: windows-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfmail

I have a Windows 7 (32bit) pc and installed ColdFusion 10. The `cfmail` tag is not working. It was working on ColdFusion 8.

Mail is going to the `ColdFusion10\cfusion\Mail\Undelivr` folder.

**(Update from comments)**
In the mail log I am seeing:

> "Error","scheduler-0","04/18/13","17:29:13",,"javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedExc‌​eption:
>   535 No SMTP server defined. Use real server address instead of
>   127.0.0.1 in your account. "

Comment: What messages do you see in the log files?  Make sure that you can ping your mail server from your ColdFusion server.  There is also a "Verify mail server connection" check box under the ColdFusion admin mail settings. Does that work for you?

Comment: in mail log i got : "Error","scheduler-0","04/18/13","17:29:13",,"javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 No SMTP server defined. Use real server address instead of 127.0.0.1 in your account. "

Comment: Have you defined the mail server in ColdFusion admin or in your cfmail tag?  It is attempting to send mail through your Windows 7 pc (localhost) which is probably not right.  See this similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899814/535-no-smtp-server-defined-use-real-server-address-instead-of-127-0-0-1-in-your

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error that you are receiving my guess would be that you have not defined the SMTP server for ColdFusion to use so it is attempting to route the mail through your Windows 7 pc.  You can define the SMTP server settings in the ColdFusion administrator for all of your `cfmail` tags. (You can also define the settings in the `cfmail` tag itself.)

Here is a [link to the docs for the mail settings under the ColdFusion administrator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ff7).

After adding the settings in the administrator be sure to check the "Verify Mail Server Connection" option. This will test the connection for you when you click the submit button. Your mail will not work until you can successfully connect to your SMTP server.